# Redis sentinel not support by istio-0.6.0 in kubernetes1.8.4

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I use spring boot 1.5.4 to build my applications.
When i use istio envoy to proxy app's network, there is a problem to connect to redis sentinel.
got error message:

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

But everything is ok when i connect to a single redis instance.
Is that istio not support sentinel now?

Comment: Maybe you can provide some details about your deployment of the sentinel? The kubernetes pods/services. How the Kubernetes service for redis is different from the Kubernetes service for sentinel?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? I see the problem is that redis-sentinel will hand out a master IP, which is not in the cluster allowed network filters in envoy. I do not yet know how to get around this rather common use case IMO.